# show texture on play screen for a little moment

Tags: libgdx

I am making game in libgdx. I want to show tutorials on game start and disappear after few seconds.My code is given below

```
public class HeroCar{
static final int TUTE_STATE_SHOW = 0;
static final int TUTE_STATE_HIDE = 1;
int tuteState;
float tuteStateTime = 0;
public HeroCar()
{
tuteState = TUTE_STATE_SHOW;
}

public void update(float deltaTime){

if(tuteStateTime >= 0.56f){
tuteStateTime = 0; 
tuteState = TUTE_STATE_HIDE;
}
else{
tuteState = TUTE_STATE_SHOW;
}
tuteStateTime += deltaTime;
}

and in game play screen class render method my code is

if(world.heroCar.tuteState == HeroCar.TUTE_STATE_SHOW){

spriteBatch.draw(Assets.speedingup_region, 480 / 2 - 172 / 2, 400, 172, 30);

}
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I want to show texts as a help to play game but disappear text after some time as tuteStateTime over as shown in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Or can can just use Car distance

```
if(herocar.position.x<50&&canShowTute)
{
fon.draw(batcher,string,posx,posy);
}
 else if(herocar.position.x>50&&canShowTute)
 {
canShowTute=false;
  }
```

This way u dont have to manage a variable for  statetime

Also if car crosses a ceratain distance than manage that no further need to show tute next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(tuteStateTime >= 0.56f){
 tuteStateTime = 0; //--------------wrong
 tuteState = TUTE_STATE_HIDE;
 }
```

donot set

```
tuteStateTime = 0
```

because if you set it 0 then in the next cycle it will check time > 0.56f , then it goes to else block and set state = show...... Hence your tutorial will never dissappear. it will always remain in show state.

Comment: Paras Mittal, when I set tuteStateTime = 0, then also increase it tuteStateTime += deltaTime at last, which show tutorial for a little time but according to you if I do not set tuteStateTime = 0 then it will never show.

Comment: I am not getting you... What exactly you wanna do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying about alpha of texture then may be this could help. 
make

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(Assets.speeding_upregion);
```

in constuctor. and in render cyle

```
float step = 0; 
float speed = 5; 
float alpha = 0; 
step = alpha > .9f ? -speed : alpha < .1f ? speed : step; alpha += step * deltaTime; 

sprite.draw(spritebatch, alpha);
```

add your condition before draw if you want to draw or not.